# VBOX: How to remove all children in branch at once

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

How to delete all snapshots in branch? Situation: I didn't need in snapshot "A" and all its children, how to remove all at once? (of course, i can remove one by one, but it too long)

Answer (score 0):

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&p=120015

Please refer this link..I hope it will helps you

> Select the specific (to be kept) snapshot, and 'Restore Snapshot'. The 'Current State' will move to the bottom of the sub-tree rooted at that kept snapshot.
>
> Repeatedly: Select the snapshot just above the 'Current State', and 'Delete Snapshot' it.
> (You will be deleting all of the child snapshots in the sub-tree, starting at the bottom and working up to the top)
>
> When you have ONLY the selected (to be kept) snapshot left, stop.

Comment: Thank you. But your way - it is "one by one" way, and I want to remove specific snapshot with all his children at once. (as I delete folders with subfolders in File Explorer)